# Como percorrer um DataSet com base nos dados contidos em um DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, ado.net, dataset

Preciso preencher um `datagridview` que já contém a relação de todos o itens. Isso com base nos registros de movimentação de materiais que constam num `DataSet`. O `datagridview` já tem todos os itens, como por exemplo: A, B, C, D., etc. E o programa vai consultar o saldo atual de item por item com base nas movimentações que constam no `DataSet`.

Pensei em fazer um `foreach` dentro do outro. Um precorre o `datagridview`, linha por linha para buscar o nome do item e o outro `foreach` interno faz a busca no `dataSet` onde estão registradas as movimentações.

Fiz dessa maneira, mas está preenchendo apenas a primeira linha da coluna Saldo.

```
void VarreDataGrid()
    {
        var resultado = 0;
        string strRowMaterial = string.Empty;

        Conexao ca = new Conexao();
        string sql = "";
        sql += " Select ";
        sql += " idRegMovimentacao, CatMovimentacao, NomeMovimentacao, codMaterial, QuantidadeMovimentada ";
        sql += " From RegistrosMovimentacao ";
        sql += " ORDER BY idRegMovimentacao ";

        ca.Conectar();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ca.cx);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "RegistrosMovimentacoes");
        if (ds.Tables["RegistrosMovimentacoes"].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            ca.Desconectar();
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvListagem.Rows)
            {
                strRowMaterial = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["codMaterial"].Value);

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["RegistrosMovimentacoes"].Rows)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(row["codMaterial"].ToString(), strRowMaterial, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                    {
                        var quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(row["QuantidadeMovimentada"]);

                        if (string.Compare(row["CatMovimentacao"].ToString(), "Entrada", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                            resultado += quantidade;

                        else
                            resultado -= quantidade; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = 0;
                    }                        

                }
                dgvListagem.CurrentRow.Cells["Saldo"].Value = resultado;
            }
        }

        ca.Desconectar();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro estava em:

dgvListagem.CurrentRow.Cells["Saldo"].Value = resultado;

Funcionou da seguinte maneira:

```
    void VarreDataGrid()
    {
        var resultado = 0;
        string strRowMaterial = string.Empty;

        Conexao ca = new Conexao();
        string sql = "";
        sql += " Select ";
        sql += " idRegMovimentacao, CatMovimentacao, NomeMovimentacao, codMaterial, QuantidadeMovimentada ";
        sql += " From RegistrosMovimentacao ";
        sql += " ORDER BY idRegMovimentacao ";

        ca.Conectar();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, ca.cx);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "RegistrosMovimentacoes");
        if (ds.Tables["RegistrosMovimentacoes"].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            ca.Desconectar();
        }
        else
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvListagem.Rows)
            {
                strRowMaterial = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells["codMaterial"].Value);

                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["RegistrosMovimentacoes"].Rows)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(row["codMaterial"].ToString(), strRowMaterial, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                    {
                        var quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(row["QuantidadeMovimentada"]);

                        if (string.Compare(row["CatMovimentacao"].ToString(), "Entrada", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0)
                            resultado += quantidade;

                        else
                            resultado -= quantidade; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultado = 0;
                    }                        

                }

            }
                dr.Cells["Saldo"].Value = resultado;
        }

        ca.Desconectar();

    }
```

Abs!